# Deploy firewall rule through Active Directory/GPO

Tags: windows, active-directory, firewall

I need to enable an existing firewall rule (or make a new one) on all the computers in a Active Directory domain. What is the best/easiest way to do this?

**EDIT:** The computers are running Windows Vista default firewall. Active Directory is run by Windows 2008 AD controllers.

Comment: what kind of firewall are you using?

Comment: I'd assume windows

Comment: What is the DFL of your AD Domain? Do you have .admx templates available, or only .adm?

Comment: I would guess 2008 and no .admx (as I'm not familiar with the templates, url?). We can't make any major change to AD. If that is required then we need to consider a scripted/programmed approach.

Comment: if you're on a 2008 DFL, then you have the .admx templates. They shipped with Server 2008.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This document should be everything you need.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=0b937897-ce39-498e-bb37-751c00f197d9&displaylang=en

This is however a bit more information than you seem to be after.

Skip to page 16 to get started, or continue on from page 32.

Due to your comment on possibly scripting the solution you can use net sh to do this.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947709

Hope this helps you.